# how to check MS office version installed on the machines 

Tags: c#, ms-office

I am working on a console app which perform some operation on registry. I am not using any interop assembly for office but i need to to know office version. How to determine which version of MS office is installed on the machine using C#.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Search in (using the [Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) class)

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths

or

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths

Version numbers are

- 7.0 -97
- 8.0 - 98
- 9.0 -2000
- 10.0 -2002
- 11.0 -2003
- 12.0 -2007
- 14.0 -2010

[Here is a c# implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/getting_office_version.aspx)

Comment: Not sure whether or not the above registry key is always reliable and safe, as I couldn't verify if it's officially supported. The better choice is the one mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266675/how-to-detect-installed-version-of-ms-office/3267832#3267832) which uses an [official registry key](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/orkXP/HA011364611033.aspx).

Comment: It doesn't always work. I have a machine with Office 2013 installed and the registry entries are not found in the given path.

Comment: Try HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Application\CurVer as well as described in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/54a0862a-f0e9-4f2f-b988-782c602a274c/have-c-check-what-version-of-excel-is-installed?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement, but I also have to find out whether office installed is 32-bit or 64-bit.  I have documented my solution here:

http://cyrilbeschi.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-find-microsoft-office-version.html