# How to get Microsoft Office path from VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, ms-office

Using VBScript, how do I determine the path where Microsoft Office (2003 or 2010) is installed?

Comment: The language is different, but the principle is the same; just check the registry key to see what is installed:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266675/how-to-detect-installed-version-of-ms-office

Comment: Did the reference by LittleBobbyTables assist? It points [to this MS link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/orkXP/HA011364611033.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the reference by LittleBobbyTables assist? It points to this MS link

```
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/orkXP/HA011364611033.aspx
```