# .net detect if Office.interop.Excel exists

Tags: .net, excel-automation

I need to use `Excel` if it is installed on the target machine, or produce a `text` file if it is not.

I check for the presence of the `excel application` registry key, but before I can do that, I get a

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c
```

or one of its dependencies.

How can I detect if an `interop` assembly is available and prevent the `run-time` trying to load it if it isn't. (I don't know what version of `Excel` may exist on the target, so I don't think I can redistribute an `interop` in case its the wrong one.)

Comment: I think this may help
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266675/how-to-detect-installed-version-of-ms-office/3267832#3267832

Comment: Have you added a reference to the Interop assembly to your object? Does the error appear before the application even starts or does it appear in a specific line of code?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you added a reference to a specific interop assembly in your code. Your application will not even load since it can't find all the assemblies it needs to run. If you absolutely have to use Excel through Interop, you will have to remove the reference and load the assembly dynamically with Assembly.Load.

You don't need Excel at all if all you want is to read/create an Excel file.

XLSX is just a bunch of zipped XML files. The [OpenXML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) by Microsoft allows you to manipulate the files withoud dealing with the XML directly and there are other libraries that sit on top of the SDK to make programming even easier.

[Generating Excel 2010 Workbooks by using the Open XML SDK 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh180830%28v=office.14%29.aspx) offers a pretty detailed explanation of the XLSX format and how you can use the SDK to create simple and complex spreadsheets easily.

Comment: Ah, legacy, legacy - I nbeed to maipilate exisitng xls files as well as xlxs files.

Comment: I plan to use Assembly.load, and catch the exceptions, but do you know where I can find the long name for the assemblies for Excel 2012 and 2010?