# can a code written for outlook 2010 work with outlook 2003

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2010, outlook-2003

We have a code written for **outlook 2010**.

When we run it on a computer using **outlook 2003**, we get an error.

We are trying to resolve user names by using Outlook.namespace GetSelectNamesDialog function

and the following exception appears when outlook 2003 is installed:

> Exception Info :System.accessviolationexception.
>
> Stack:
>
> at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace.GetSelectNamesDialog()

Is there any way that our code will work for both **2010** and **2003**?

for now, it works just for outlook 2010.

Comment: if you have used features of outlook 2010 not available in 2003, you may not be able to run it. But provide more details, specifics, code, error messages

Comment: Which interop libraries are you using for Outlook?

Comment: Im using microsoft.office.interop.outlook pia/office12. The exception info: system.accessviolationexception. its appear when i try to do ctrl+k to add users.

Comment: We are trying to resolve user names by using outlook.namespace GetSelectNamesDialog and the following exception appears when outlook 2003 is installed: accessviolationexception. What can i do about it?

Answer (score 1):

you can implement 2 classes.
one for 2010 and the other for 2003.
make an interface of OutlookExchange with 3 function :send,resolve and close.
those 2 classes will Inheritance from OutlookExchange.
you need to check what is the outlook version that installed in your computer explnation in the next link [How to detect installed version of MS-Office?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266675/how-to-detect-installed-version-of-ms-office)
, and use the class  according to the version like that:

```
public static OutlookCreator()

{


Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appVer = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

string[] _appVer=appVer.Split('.');

int version=Int32.Parse(_appVer[0]);

OutlookExchange exchange=null;

//outlook 2003

if(version==11)

   exchange=new Outlook2003();

//outlook 2007 and newer

if(version>11)

   exchange=new Outlook2010();

return exchange

}
```