# Saving Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word

I would like to save a Word document according to the Word installed version;

In case it is Word  2003  (appropriate version number is 11), with `DOC` extension.
In case the Word version is higer than 2003, with `DOCX` extension.

The difference is reflected in the second argument sent to the `SaveAS` method:

```
object fileFormat = GraphDocsSettings.Default.WordInstalledVersion > 11.0?     
                WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument : WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument;

wordDoc.SaveAs(ref outputFile, fileFormat, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                           ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                           ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                           ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

However, When using Interop.Word 11.0 I get the following error:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WDSaveFormat does not contain a definition for wdFormatXMLDocument.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a read of the accepted answer on this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266675/how-to-detect-installed-version-of-ms-office

Comment: @PaulZahra, Thanks, I know already what is the installed version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure the API is exactly the same between different word versions.

If I can make a suggestion - use NetOffice( [see link](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/)) instead of the office interop assemblies.

the API is the same as the Office Interop API, and it will work with all (current) versions of Microsoft Office.

NB - Here is a sample: http://netoffice.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Word_Example01

You should import the following namespaces to get it to work:

```
using NetOffice;
using Word = NetOffice.WordApi;
using NetOffice.WordApi.Enums;
using Office = NetOffice.OfficeApi;
```

Comment: Seems a good suggestion. What is the difference between  NetOffice and Office Interop PIAs?

Comment: NetOffice is a wrapper for the Office Com Interface, it uses LateBinding / reflection under the hood though, hence the ability to work with any Office Version. See the documentation for more info

Comment: Have I to attach a dll just like I did With Office PIAs?

Comment: If the assemblies are referenced as part of your project they should automatically be included in the build - no effort needed. You can get the NetOffice assemblies via NuGet anyway, so even easier!

Comment: NB - there is no need to reference the Office PIA assemblies anymore, so you can remove them from your project references

Comment: Thanks,  I need some help with migrating my code to this assemblies. I have downloaded the link you brought. Now, Where are the dlls to attach as references?

Comment: Do you have the NuGet Package Manager Installed? If not I'd recommend you install this (From Tools -> extensions and Updates) After that right click on your project -> Manage Nuget Packages. Then search for NetOffice. Install the packages NetOffice.Core.Net45 and NetOffice.Word.Net45 (for .net4.5, or whatever your version) You can of course just download manually, unpack, and add a reference instead if you want though

Comment: Not so fluency conversion. I get the following error : `Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'NetOffice.WordApi.Enums.WdWindowState' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdWindowState'. An explicit conversion exists ` when I do `wordApp.WindowState = WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMinimize;` Any ideas?

Comment: remove all references to the Microsoft.Office.Interop assemblies from your project and classes - just use the references I've posted above instead In particular at the top of your class you should have: `using NetOffice.WordApi.Enums;` and NOT `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`

Comment: Fine, That solved the problem. Now I get the strange exception "See inner exception for more details" when I create a ne file based on a template `wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref oTemplate, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);` Thanks for your detailed answers!

Comment: Best post the innerexcepion then! However from looking at the NetOffice API it looks like there are usually overloads which mean you dont need to pass all the optional parameters as ref missing. None of the examples show passing parameters as ref, so you're probably ok with just `wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(oTemplate);` Look at the linked example in my answer, or others on the site.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you use the wrong version of the interop assemblies. You cannot reference a value which only exists in higher versions of the framework.

You should use a higher interop version, or create two separate projects, one for the older version of the interop assemblies, one for the higher versions.

Comment: Can I use a higher interop for 2003?

Comment: @user3165438: I didn't think so. I thought the framework versions were to different to be downward compatible. Upwards does work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following project's code base to create and save ms word using c#: 
https://github.com/kauser-cse-buet/NetOfficeUsage