# Visual studio Word Addin 2010 does not load in office 2007

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, ms-word, visual-studio-addins

I have developed word addin 2010 using visual studio 2012. I have created setup file using below MSDN link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx

When i run this for ofice 2010 or office 2013 it works fine but it doesn't work for office 2007.

I though it would be word addin issue so I have created word addin 2007 and still have issue.

Can somebody suggest what can be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Add-in functionality changed again between Office 2007 and 2010, to support new features like the changed UI (RibbonBar). The addin you created for Office 2010 uses features that did not exist in the Office 2007 apps (Word/Excel etc).

Office Add-ins are typically *forward compatible* only. That is *future version of Office support older older plugins*, but the opposite is simply not possible as new features get added all the time.

### e.g.

- Write an Office 2007 addin and it will likely work on Office 2007, Office 2010 and Office 2013.
- Write an Office 2010 addin and it will likely work on Office 2010 and Office 2013.
- Write an Office 2013 addin and it will likely *only* work on Office 2013.

Please note that while they "work" they will often look very old-fashioned as they typically use the older UI elements and not the latest version.

### Create a 2007 add-in instead

If you really need Office 2007 support, you need to create a 2007 Add-in instead (as well?). Otherwise you will likely be using features that simply do not exist in Office 2007. The only possible (unlikely) alternative is to add Office 2010 DLLs to the machines, but as you are then effectively upgrading Office I doubt that is legal without a Office 2010 licence (so you might as well upgrade them anyway).

Comment: Do i have to develop Word 2007 Addin on machine having office 2007? The machine on which i am developing word addin has office 2010. i have tried with word 2007 addin but it has not added button to any of the office version(2007,2010,2013). i am really confused. would you please provide more guidance? The below MSDN link says that word 2010 addin is compatible with word 2007.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb772080.aspx

Comment: You just need the dev kit and the interop DLLs. They key part of that link you provided says *"However, the solution can use only those features and APIs that are available in all three versions of Office."*. If you can *dumb down* your add-in to not use any Office 2010 features, it should work.

Comment: I am not using any of the office 2010 features. When i install this on machine having word 2007, It adds the wordaddin as COM Add-Ins but the load behavior is unloaded.

Comment: OK, if you are not using any features of 2010, then the problem is elsewhere. Are you able to provide any code or config/xml for your addin? It is very difficult to sort this out from a description alone.

Comment: I Can provide you code but Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to copy whole code or attach the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach to the project the `Interop.Word` dll of Word 2007.
Also exchange the `Office Object Library dll 12`- which comes along with Word 2007.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So i will get these dll's on machine having word 2007 installed? There are other Dll's like Microsoft.Office.Tools, Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common etc.. Do we have to change these reference as well?

Comment: From a machine which Word 2007 is installed on, attach the DLLs I mentioned as references.

Comment: Word 2010 add-ins contain support for new features *that do not exist in Word 2007*. How do you expend them to bridge that gap?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, The goal is to allow the program to run also with Word 2007. Then, if there are problems we know it uses API of later versions of Word. To avoid this situation there is an option to use other wrapped DLLs instead of the office DLLs. Make sense? [Look here for such a dll for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23239930/saving-word-document)

Comment: Actually that does not makes sense to me. Please see my answer and see if that covers what you mean by *other wrapped DLLs*.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, Upvoted. However, maybe there is no use of the new features of Word 2010 or higher, and just replacing the DLLs is enough.

Comment: It they used the standard app wizard, it will have a Ribbon Bar that is exclusive to 2010 onwards.