# Get installed office version through code or registry

Tags: python, ms-office

My requirement is to identify version of ms office installed.

whether MSOffice 2007 is installed or MSOffice 2010 is installed or MSOffice 2013 is installed or MSOffice 2016 is installed.

I need to get above information either through code by some API, or by reading any particular registry key. Registry key which is common and consistent across all version of MSOffice.

I also do not prefer to look in to office applications version like version of word,outlook or excel to decide MSOffice version as i am not sure how consistent is that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect installed version of MS-Office?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266675/how-to-detect-installed-version-of-ms-office)

Answer (score 2):

Please check out the following articles, they will help you to figure out the way for determining whether Office is installed and what applications and versions:

- [How to Determine the Path for an Office Application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240794)
- [Description of the numbering scheme for product code GUIDs in Office 2010](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2186281)
- [How to determine which version of a 2007 Office product is installed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928116)
- [How to determine the service pack level of your Office 2010 suite](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2121559)

Typically the windows registry path contains numbers that indicate the Office version. For example:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook
```

where `15.0` stands for Office 2013 and etc.

Comment: Thanks Astafiev for respone.
I specifically need MSOffice version (12.0,14.0,15.0 or 16.0) but not by checking versions of office applications like outlook , word.Since i am not sure how much consistent is that. Is there any common registry  to get version of MSoffice itself like **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\common\ ** or windows MSI API you have an idea of.

Comment: When you install an Office 2010 suite or one of the stand-alone Office 2010 programs, one or more product codes, or GUIDs, are created in the following registry subkey:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Each GUID uses the following format:
{BRMMmmmm-PPPP-LLLL-p000-D000000FF1CE}

Comment: See [Description of the numbering scheme for product code GUIDs in Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2186281) for more information.

Comment: I have office 2016 installed on my machine,But there is no entry for same at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion‌​\Uninstall.
Is there single registry key or api to get office version for all MSOffices (2007,2010,2013,1016)