# Microsoft Office 2019 registry entry question

Tags: vba, ms-word, registry

Question for someone who has MS Office 2019 installed. I don't have it.
Office 2016 created this registry entry:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options

When 2019 is installed is the above entry used or is this created:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\19.0\Word\Options

I suspect "16.0" but can't verify and need to assist someone and knowing this will be helpful.

The below thread was helpful but did not address this question specifically:
[How to detect Office 2019 programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892882/how-to-detect-office-2019-programmatically)

Comment: Might be better to ask this in the TechNet forums - it's not truly a programming question...

Comment: Do you mean social.technet.microsoft.com? I hope I don't insult anyone here but no thanks. I don't find those answers helpful. I can try another forum if needed.

Comment: That is the forum I meant. Perhaps its quality has changed since last I looked in there, but in my experience that's usually where knowledge about installation defaults, network administration etc. has been present (and what it should cover).

Answer (score 0):

Office 2019 are using the 16.0 subkey of standard registry. Nothing changed from 2016 here.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried below?
`FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path.Combine(officeinstallpath, WINWORD.EXE"))`;

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?