# Powershell Test-Path Office 365 PRO PLUS

Tags: powershell, directory, office365

I want to use Test-Path for Microsoft Office 365 PRO PLUS.

I used this code but I want to go for the executable to make sure it is really installed. Please see the code below:

$Office = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15"

$testoffice = Test-Path $Office

If ($testoffice -eq $true) {Write-Host "Office 365 exist!"}

Else {Write-Host "Office 365 doesn't exist!"}

Read-Host "Press enter to exit"

Am I using the right directory for it? Is there an executable to make sure the installation went through and not just the folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect installed version of MS-Office?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266675/how-to-detect-installed-version-of-ms-office)

Answer (score 2):

The best way is via the registry. It checks specifically for 365 and there's no redundancy in case there's a different version of office.

```
$uninstallKeys = Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

$O365 = "Microsoft Office 365"
$O365Check = $uninstallKeys | Where-Object { $_.GetValue("DisplayName") -match $O365 }


if ($O365Check) {

Write-Output "Found Office!"
}
else {

Write-Output "No Office here!"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used rad_'s answer but found that it didn't work for me and had to use something different. I also opened reg edit and did a search for "Microsoft Office 365" just to get the following.

```
$Office365 = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Registration\{003D2533-6A8C4163-9A4E-76376B21ED15}" -Name "ProductName"
$O365 = "Microsoft Office 365"

if ($Office365 -match $O365) {
    Write-Host "You have Office 365, no need for the update. [√]" -ForegroundColor Green
} else {
    Write-Host "No Office 365 installed [X]" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```