# How to get Version Number by Build Number Office

Tags: ms-word, office365, vsto, ms-office

I'm working VSTO and I have an issue.
I want to get a Version of Office but I can't

[image]

I want to get 2008

Please help me! Thanks

I'm using C#

Answer (score 1):

You can get the file version information of the Office application.

```
// Retrieve the path e.g. from the InstallRoot Registry key
var fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE");
var version = new Version(fileVersionInfo.FileVersion);

// or you can get the information from the running instance using the `Process` class
var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("winword").First();
string fileVersionInfo = process.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileVersion;
var version = Version(fileVersionInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I got a detailed version. Now I want to get a Version of the build office

Comment: Based on the detailed version you may find the version (2008 I guess on the picture). The versions and their build numbers are published in MSDN.

Comment: But in MSDN have many version...I can't get it by hand. I think it may be at the registry or anywhere on the computer. But I don't know

Comment: You may find the [How to detect installed version of MS-Office?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266675/how-to-detect-installed-version-of-ms-office) thread helpful.

Comment: After looking for so long, your first example was the only good way I found to get the full version + build version. Thank you!