# VBA to detect the office versions with their corresponding bit also

Tags: vba, outlook

I have both the 32 and 64 bit version of Office 2010. If I need to install VSTO 2 for 2010 Office 32 bit machines and install VSTO 4 64 bit for 2010 Office 64 bit machines

```
Public Function checkbitversion() As Variant
#If VBA7 Then
    checkbitversion = "64"
#Else
    checkbitversion = "32"
#End If
End Function
```

but it always results as 32 bit for all machines. I need help to overcome the problem.

I refer to the following MSDN article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700513%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896645/how-to-check-ms-office-version-installed-on-the-machines ?

Comment: Are you compiling your application using `VBA7` as a constant?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Bitness value in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\version\Outlook

Where version above is 14.0 or 15.0 depending on the Outlook version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, untested, from the second forum post from > [HERE](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/542727-determining-if-os-32-bit-64-bit-using-visual-basic-applications.html).

```
Function Is64bit() As Boolean
Is64bit = Len(Environ("ProgramW6432")) > 0
End Function
```

He says `The logic seems to be if that environment variable returns anything or not, as that parameter probably doesn't exist in the 32-bit version.`

If it returns something it is 64 bit, otherwise it is 32 bit, per his description.